# How can I render HTML content in an R Shiny Popify (ShinyBS) tooltip?

Tags: html, r, shiny, dt, shinybs

I'm building out a datatable in R Shiny and part of it will include tooltips unique to each cell. I've accomplished that, however, I seem to be unable to insert HTML content into the tooltip itself. In the example below, I'm inserting HTML content into a cell in the datatable, and then aim to insert that same content into a tooltip, but the HTML only renders in the datatable, and not in the tooltip.

I've played around with a few ideas but can't find any that work. I can get the HTML to appear (as text) in the tooltip by removing the HTML function, but then, obviously, it's escaped and is just text. I am able to bold text within the tooltip using tags$b(), however, I am hoping for a solution more similar to my example below as I have more complex HTML content I would like add to the tooltip beyond just text.

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  bsTooltip('tbutton',''),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput('df'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- data.frame(A = c(1:5), B = c(LETTERS[1:5]))
  
  output$df <- renderDataTable({
    
    cell <- paste0('<svg width="30" height="30">',
                   '<text x="1%" y="75%" font-weight="bold" font-size="16" >B</text>',
                   '</svg>')
    
    df[2,2] <- as.character(popify(tags$div(HTML(cell)),
                                   title = 'Tooltip:',
                                   placement = 'left',
                                   content = paste0(tags$div(HTML(cell))),
                                   trigger = c('hover', 'click')))
    
    datatable(df, escape=FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

To attach a popover to a cell, you can use `bsPopover` if this cell has an `id`. To set an `id` to the cells, you can use the **datatables** option `createdCell`.

Then the HTML code works in the popover content, but not the SVG (or at least I didn't manage to make it work).

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = LETTERS[1:5])

css <- "
.red {color: red;}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput('df'),
    bsPopover(
      id = "id2",
      title = "test",
      content = '<p class="red">TEST</p>'
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$df <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      df,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = 2,
            createdCell = JS(
              "function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {",
              "  $(td).attr('id', 'id' + (row+1));",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```